# The Menu in bold keeps saying its a syntax error and i dont know how to fix it

Tags: python, python-3.x

The Menu() function keeps saying its a syntax error and I don't know how to fix it.

```
global celebritydoggame
def Menu():
        print ("Play,Quit Or Cards")
        choise = input(">?")
        if input == "Play" or "play":
            Deck()
        elif input == "Quit" or "quit":
            print("Thank You")
            quit()
        elif input == "Cards" or "cards":
                cards()

def cards():
        myfile = ("dogs.txt","r")


def Deck():
        print("How many cards do you want to play with in the game?")
        print("The amount of cards must be between 4-30, also you must choose a even number.")
        num = input(">?")
        if input == int >30:
           print ("error")
        elif input == int (4) <30:
            print ("ok the number of cards in play are"("int"))  
        elif input == int(num(4> int(num(30<
             print("Total of Cards must be over 4, under 30 and a even number"))

Menu()
```

Comment: Can you provide some additional information? Traceback, for example. Also, your conditionals seems wrong: e.g. write `input == "Play" or "play"` as `input == "Play" or input == "play"`

Answer (score 1):

You have a redundant parenthesis at the end of `Deck` function.

Also, your conditionals seems wrong: e.g. rewrite

```
if input == "Play" or "play":
```

as

```
if input == "Play" or input == "play"
```

UPD: You actually have many mistakes in `Dock` functions, almost every `print` and `if` is wrong. I strongly suggest you learn python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

it is happening because of the last two lines in the `Deck()` function.

```
elif input == int(num(4> int(num(30<
         print("Total of Cards must be over 4, under 30 and a even number"))
```

here you haven't closed the brackets properly.

there is also a problem with `if` statement in `Deck()` function.

```
if input == int >30:
```

`input` is a function that takes in value  from the user.

there is a mistake in almost every `if` and `elif` statement.

even in `Menu()` function it should have been something like this :

```
if input == "Play" or input == "play":
        Deck()
```